# Order MySQL inbox by newest conversation first?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a MySQL/PHP code for a private messaging system that I built. It works great although I'm fairly new to it all so struggling to get the message threads to display by newest first. Is there any chance you could offer advice? The current code is as follows:

```
$result = '';

$nowTime = time();

$getmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_to = '$session_memberid' GROUP BY msg_from ORDER BY ID DESC");
while($iamessages = mysql_fetch_array($getmessages))
{
$msg_id = $iamessages['ID'];
$msg_from = $iamessages['msg_from'];
$msg_conversation = $iamessages['conversation'];



$getmsgdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_to = '$session_memberid' AND msg_from = '$msg_from' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
while($imsd = mysql_fetch_array($getmsgdata))
{
$msg_message = $imsd['msg_message'];
$msg_time = $imsd['time'];
$msg_read = $imsd['msg_read'];
}

$msg_conversation = suitcrypt($msg_conversation);

if ( $msg_read == 'no' ) { $msgclass = "messagepostunread"; } else { $msgclass = "messagepost"; }

$getfromdata = mysql_query("SELECT FullName, Username, status FROM members WHERE ID = '$msg_from'");
while($ifd = mysql_fetch_array($getfromdata))
{
$msg_from_name = $ifd['FullName'];
$msg_from_username = $ifd['Username'];
$msg_from_status = $ifd['status'];
}

$getfromdata1 = mysql_query("SELECT Link FROM images WHERE MemberID = '$msg_from' AND is_primary = 'yes'");
while($ifd1 = mysql_fetch_array($getfromdata1)) {
$msg_from_img = $ifd1['Link'];
}

$timepass = timing($msg_time);
if ( $timepass == 'data' ) {
$timepass = date("dS M", $msg_time);
}

if ( ( $msg_from_status == 'full' ) || ( $msg_from_status == 'active' ) ) {

$result .= "
        <div class=\"$msgclass\" onclick=\"showconversation('$msg_conversation');\">
        <img src=\"m/members_image/$msg_from/thumb-$msg_from_img\" class=\"feedpic\" width=\"55\" height=\"55\" /><div class=\"messageposttext\"><a href=\"/$msg_from_username\">$msg_from_name</a>:<div class=\"inboxfeedreply\">Reply &nbsp; &middot; &nbsp; $timepass</div><br />$msg_message</div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"splittermessages\"></div>
";
}
```

Within each table entry in the messages table there is a 'time' stamp. Here's an example of the time entries: 1367680391. What's the best way to order the threads by newest reply first?

Comment: Have you tried to order by the timestamp instead of id?

Comment: I can't see why you don't simply `order by time desc` instead of `order by id desc`. I also would join tables together, since many requests for a package of data is slower than one good join.

Comment: I tried order by time desc but it didn't seem to change anything :/ It seems to always just order by the time that the initial message in the conversation thread was sent rather than the latest message in the conversation thread.

Comment: @EdzJohnson Why do you group by msg_from in your first query? I think you should instead group by $msg_conversation

Comment: Would be nice to have a description of your table(s) in order to help more.

Comment: ...and the usual caveats about the deprecation of the mysql_ api

Answer (score 0):

First off I think you should group by $msg_conversation and find the last date on each conversation. With the code below you have the conversatons ordered by the last message each conversation/thread had.

```
$result = '';

$nowTime = time();

$getmessages = mysql_query("SELECT conversation, max(date) FROM messages WHERE msg_to = '$session_memberid' GROUP BY conversation ORDER BY max(date)");
while($iamessages = mysql_fetch_array($getmessages))
{
$msg_conversation = $iamessages['conversation'];
...
```

Further on you can get the messages for each conversation by date descending.

Answer (score 0):

I got someone to help and the answer was to update the query to the following:

```
$getmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_to = '$session_memberid' GROUP BY msg_from ORDER BY MAX(time) DESC");
```